# Is it possible to Embeded VBA code by PHPspreadsheet?

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Regarding the question below since 2015, I now also want to do the same thing. I tried to search everywhere but stil find no answer.

So I want to ask you guys if is it now possible or not in 2022.?

[Embedding VBA code in Excel using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993952/embedding-vba-code-in-excel-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility for any PHP library for writing VBA Excel spreadsheets.

[enter link description here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28700186/PHPExcel-Deletes-Embedded-VBA.html)